# Matching a complicated pattern in SQL Server LIKE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pattern-matching, sql-like

I am using a stored procedure that pulls in a string parameter and uses this as part of a `WHERE table.value LIKE @pattern` clause to one of its queries. Before anyone jumps down my throat about the dangers this invokes, the procedure is being called with one of a set of known values as the pattern parameter -- there is no direct pass from user input to this parameter.

For individual cases, this works. My possible patterns are:

```
"RBI-%-TH%N-[AB]-%"
"RBI-%-TH%N-C-%"
"RBI-%-TH%N-D-%"
"RBI-%-VISUAL%"
```

Where I am running into an issue is in trying to cover all four of those by setting a default pattern (which will select all records where `table.value` matches any of those patterns, but nothing else) . The first three are easy enough with `"RBI-%-TH%N-[ABCD]-%"` however I haven't been able to find a good way to account for the final possible value. Is there a good way, or do I need to complicate the stored procedure with logic to handle this condition?

Answer (score 0):

Is

```
select ... from ...
where [value] like "RBI-%-TH%N-[ABCD]-%" or [value] like "RBI-%-VISUAL%"
```

not sufficient?

Comment: If I must go that route, I will. I am hoping to be able to cover both cases with a single pattern. There's a lot more that's going into the procedure than this, and it keeps things quite a bit simpler if I can just pass in a single pattern parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another variation using UNION ALL that depending on the cardinality may result in more limited range scans, but chances are you are in for some long running scans no matter how you construct the query. You'll have to test some of the variations and review the execution plans to see how performance actually stacks up when these are run against your data. Is setting up and using Free Text Search an option?

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE [value] like "RBI-%-TH%N-[A]-%" 
UNION ALL
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE [value] like "RBI-%-TH%N-[B]-%" 
UNION ALL
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE [value] like "RBI-%-TH%N-[C]-%" 
UNION ALL
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE [value] like "RBI-%-TH%N-[D]-%" 
UNION ALL
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE [value] like "RBI-%-VISUAL%";
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question at:

[TSQL - Pattern Matching with Like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753527/tsql-pattern-matching-with-like)

And there were some good answers.  I think the one that would help you the best is to put your possible patterns into a new table and then join the tables as suggested by MaxiWheat.