# TSQL - Pattern Matching with Like

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, pattern-matching

I am using SQL server 2012.

I know I can use Like in a query to match a pattern in the database:

ie

```
SELECT * from PEOPLE where name LIKE 'STEVE%'
```

would return all people called steve.

But can I have the wildcards in the data instead of the query.

For instance I have a database that has those patterns in

```
Row     Input                 Response
  1     '% is a sort of %'    'I know that.'
```

How would I be able to match a user input of 'VW is a sort of Car' to the data in row 1?

For backgrounds sake I've been looking at chatbots recently and they routinely do this sort of matching via XML files.

For bonus points how do I store the % values in a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically you do `WHERE column LIKE @variable` but why can't you do it the other way around?

```
DECLARE @x TABLE([Row] INT, Input VARCHAR(32), Response VARCHAR(32));

INSERT @x([Row],Input,Response) SELECT 1, '% is a sort of %', 'I know that.';

DECLARE @variable VARCHAR(32) = 'VW is a sort of Car';

SELECT [Row], Input, Response
    FROM @x
    WHERE @variable LIKE [Input];
```

Comment: Wow, I had no idea you could invert it that way.  That's....very powerful!  Thank You Aaron.  This should scale nicely.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually use this kind of table which contains a list of patterns and have those patterns "applied" in a query like this :

```
SELECT PT.pattern AS matching_pattern, 
       ST.searched_field AS matched_value
FROM Pattern_Table AS PT
    INNER JOIN Searched_Table AS ST ON ST.searched_field LIKE PT.pattern
```

This will output something like :

```
matching_pattern    matched_value
% is a sort of %    VW is a sort of Car
```

[Have a look at it on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9864/1) (even if it is MySQL it still works)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks MaxiWheat, that gives me exactly what I want in the first instance.  I guess I'd then need to pass the string into a function and use substring to get the values of "VW" and "car"?

Comment: I've gone with the solution that produces the simpler solution and query plan.  but thanks for taking the time to answer, and also thanks for introducing me to SQL fiddle.  That's definitely worth an upvote once I have the power to do so:)

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions will give you access to the parts of the pattern that it matched.  I assume that's what you mean by "store the % in a variable":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx

Comment: RegEx seems like extreme overkill for the example in the question.

Comment: Thanks AaronLS, I'll definitely be looking more into Regex in the future as it looks like there is some functionality there that could extend what I want to do.  However I'd have to learn it from scratch, so for now I think I'll go with the simpler solution.  thanks very much for your response though.

Comment: @Aaron That's the only solution I know of that meets the asker's requirement to be able to extract the string that the wildcard matched.  I didn't have enough details to say if it is overkill or not, just that it met their requirement.  I sold them the hammer.  I didn't ask them what they were going to do with it :)

Comment: I'm just saying that SQL Server can perform a simple pattern match using LIKE without having to involve CLR and RegEx. For more complicated problems, sure, but for this one it's not necessary. In addition, your answer doesn't really tell them what to do once they have RegEx installed. They still didn't know that you could flip the WHERE clause the way I showed...

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes LIKE can perform a simple pattern match, but he asked a followup question about a way to extract the portion matching the wildcard.  You can't do that with a simple LIKE pattern match, bottom line.  "how do I store the % values in a variable?"  Bottom line LIKE can't do that, I gave him an option that can.  If the requirement is absolutely necessary, then there's nothing overkill about the solution.  If the requirement is not very important to him, then yes a Regex is probably overkill.  How important that particular requirement is to his solution, is for him to judge.

Comment: Still your answer just points at a link that shows what CLR/RegEx is. It is probably better suited as a comment than an answer. IMHO.

Comment: @AaronLS Perhaps you would like to explain and add body to the answer on how RegEx is used here? The current answer reads like `LIKE will solve your problem` without really answering

Comment: @AaronBertrand No it doesn't just point at a link.  Take out the link and it's still an answer. He asked a question "how do I store the % values in a variable?", I answered with the SQL feature that will give him that capability.  LIKE will not solve that problem, I pointed him in the direction of a feature that will.  No I didn't write a full on How-To article, and that is not a requirement of an answer.  It would be a waste for me to go to that effort given that he ultimately decided that was not that important to him.

Comment: I think it's even less helpful without the link. But whatever.

Comment: I will just delete this answer since I'm being harrassed for it.  And anyone else who comes here can be ignorant of the fact that there is actually a solution that meets that requirement if they are in need of it.  I thought the purpose was to serve as a future bank of knowledge for others with a similar problem.

Comment: @AaronBertrand  Thank you for agreeing with my decision to include a link, because it does indeed make it more helpful.  I thought, will it not be more useful if I found an article that teaches him how to implement the feature?  So I included it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand You know what, I don't really care about what you have to say.  You were wrong to begin with on your first point, and when you lost that argument you kept trying with "Still your answer just".  If you want to put this much effort into being negative, then I'll leave it here for all to see. My answer contributes something that no other answer does, it is a response to one of his questions, therefore is an answer.  I don't have to write a full on article on regex for it to be considered an answer.  If he expressed an interested in using the solution I would spend more time on it.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi I never said "LIKE will solve your problem".  Please quote me as having said that.  Y'all are trying so hard to be negative you're even making stuff up.

Comment: I think the distinction between a comment and an answer has been missed. Both can be helpful. *shrug*

Comment: @AaronLS What I meant is, your answer is about the same quality level as "Q: How do I partially match strings in SQL Server?" "A: Use LIKE, you can include wildcards." and then a link covering the general use case for `LIKE` without relating to OP's context. You might consider it an "answer". I personally consider it a "comment".

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi No one else has answered the specific question that I addressed.  A response to a question is an answer.  Something is better than nothing.  My expectation is that they would then go off and make an attempt to use the feature using examples and documentation, and come back if they have problems.  Where do you draw the line on an answer?  There is no requirement that I produce a fully functioning compilable solution for someone who is likely not even going to use it: "However I'd have to learn it from scratch, so for now I think I'll go with the simpler solution."

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi I don't see anyone else jumping at the chance to work through some regex just produce a solution that meets that one corner case when the asker has already said they are satisfied without that requirement.  I leave the answer here so that people who might need that same requirement will know that while LIKE cannot accomplish it, that regex can.  If they have difficulty implementing a solution based on their specific scenario, then they should post their regex attempts with their existing effort.

Comment: Note to self: don't spend so much time on stackoverflow that you become a pedantic elitist and give people **** for trying to help others.

Answer (score 0):

you can do a very similar search

```
where input like '%is a sort of%'
```

or you can look up REGULAR EXPRESSIONS `regex` for more complicated pattern matching